# Does explicit template instantiation go in cpp or header file?

Tags: c++, templates

Does explicit template instantiation go in cpp or header file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've always done it in a cpp file. In a header, it would violate the one definition rule, at least (in the usual case) when the header was included in more than one cpp file (though there are ways to avoid that, which can be useful under a few, specific circumstances).

Comment: What if you are declaring a class member?

Comment: _"In a header, it would violate the one definition rule, at least (in the usual case) when the header was included in more than one cpp file."_ - for most cases, correct, but [there is an essential well-formed workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72379134/4573247) useful in the domains of hacks like FB's folly library and stateful meta-programming.

Comment: @dfrib: Yeah, I suppose that's worth mentioning. Edited.

Comment: @JerryCoffin The edit missed the mark: it is not about placing the implicit instantiation definition in an unnamed namespace (this doesn't make a difference, it still runs into ODR when included in multiple TU's), it's about making sure the explicit instantiation def. defines a specialization where at least one type template parameter is specialized by a type defined in an unnamed namespace in same header as the implicit instantiation definition: such a type will be unique in each TU meaning the specialization which is instantiated is unique in every TU, and we can avoid violating the ODR.

Comment: @dfrib: yeah, I don't want to get into too much detail about something that's usually just a distraction for most people who are at all likely to read this.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Yes that’s reasonable, and now with the new edit and the fewer details it’s no longer inaccurate. Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

Assuming by "explicit template instantiation" you mean something like

```
template class Foo<int>; // explicit type instantiation
// or
template void Foo<int>(); // explicit function instantiation
```

then these **must** go in source files as they considered definitions and are consequently subject to the [ODR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

Comment: Good answer, but to get a bit picky: certain template definitions which should be put in header files are still technically definitions.  (And the "other" section of the ODR, about all definitions having identical content and meaning, applies to them.)

Comment: @aschepler : But, explicit template instantiations are no longer templates and are not subject to the same rules as templates; rather, they are subject to the same rules as normal class or function definitions, which (excepting `inline` for functions) are *always* subject to the ODR.

Comment: _"[...] then these must go in source files"_ - for most cases, correct, but [there is an essential well-formed special case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72379134/4573247) useful in the domains of hacks like FB's folly library and stateful meta-programming.

Answer (score -3):

Either one.

If you are declaring a specific instance, you might declare it in your cpp file. However, if you are declaring a class member or something that will be referenced from multiple cpp files, that would go in your header file.

Comment: A downvote with no explanation? About as lame as it gets folks.

Comment: Maybe because it's wrong? The OP asked about explicit instantiations, not declarations or typedefs.

Comment: Not typedefs, no. But where is the explicit instantiation of a template that is declared as a class member?

Comment: @Jonathan Wood : The *declaration* would go in the header, as per usual, but the *explicit instantiation* would go in a source file just as with any non-template class or function definitions. I don't see what you're getting at...

Comment: @ildjarn: If it's a class member, then you can only instantiate the class. Classes can't be inline. Forget it.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood : Class members that are (member) function templates can be explicitly instantiated. Classes cannot be inline and thus are subject to the ODR, as is *my* point; again, what is *your* point?