# When exporting an explicitly instantiated template, do you put the EXPORT statements on the template or on the explicit template instantiation?

Tags: c++, templates, cmake, shared-libraries

Say that I am making a shared library and have set:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET hidden)
```

So that I must manually export the public API.  Now say that I have a templated class that is split into 2 files:  a `my_lib.hpp` which contains just the declaration:

```
template <typename Scalar>
class MyLibClass { ... };
```

and a `my_lib.cpp` which contains the implementation and explicit instantiation:

```
...
template class MyLibClass<float>;
template class MyLibClass<double>;
```

I then use CMake's `generate_export_header()` to generate a `my_lib_export.hpp` file which contains the appropriate export declarations.  Which file should I include it into?  In the header it would be:

```
#include "my_lib_export.hpp"
class MY_LIB_EXPORT MyLibCass { ... };
```

While in the implementation file, it would be:

```
#include "my_lib_export.hpp"
...
template class MY_LIB_EXPORT MyLibClass<float>;
template class MY_LIB_EXPORT MyLibClass<double>;
```

In my very simple example, both compile and link without issue.  But I'm wondering, is there a difference between the two?  Do they serve different purposes, or are they completely interchangeable?

Comment: @revision#1: what cpp? Doesn't the explicit instantiation need to be available at compile time? If the explicit instantiated template is part of the public interface of the library, shouldn't there be no "cpp" file for it (and everything go in the header)?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question because, as far as I'm aware (and as described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864438/8304579) an explicit instantiation of a template **must** go in the implementation file, and not the header.

Comment: @user not always. IF you have a template, because implementation details are repeated, but you only want the template to be available for a set of types, you can hide the template implementation and force generation for those types. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2155790/1294207

Comment: headers are source files too.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox whoops. completely forgot about that. I even do that in a project of my own :P